# What metrics would I need to make a custom Plugin to report PHP app memory consumption for new relic?

Tags: plugins, newrelic

I've installed the Ruby SDK to build a custom New Relic plugin, but have no clue where to go from there. No one in the forum seems to have a problem with creating a custom plugin so I'm missing something. I just need to be pointed in the right direction. I need the plugin to simply show the time again memory chart for the PHP app being monitored, exactly like the one available in the default dashboard. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ruby example plugin](https://github.com/newrelic-platform/newrelic_example_plugin/blob/master/newrelic_example_agent) has some starting examples on how to use the New Relic Ruby SDK to report metrics.

The basic format is `report_metric(metricName, Units, metricValue)` where the metricName is what you want displayed in New Relic, the units are what your metric is measured in and the metricValue is the numeric data itself that changes over time.